# Python2.6 syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, python-2.6

I'm writting some scripts in Python2.6. I always write in python2.7 so I don't know why this sentence is wrong:

```
keys = ['h','b']
d = {k:0 for k in keys if not k in ['time_us', 'status']}
```

The error:

> print (sys.version)
>
> 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Mar 15 2018, 13:11:05)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
>
> keys = ['b','h']
>
> d = {k:0 for k in keys if not k in ['time_us', 'status']}
>
> File "", line 1
>
> ```
> d = {k:0 for k in keys if not k in ['time_us', 'status']}
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Yes it  is! Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions came along in Python 2.7.

For Python 2.6, you can pass [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) a sequence of key-value pairs.

```
d = dict((k,0) for k in keys if k not in ('time_us', 'status'))
```

Comment: This returns an error in last dict.

Comment: >>> d = dict((k,0) for k in keys if k not in {'n'})
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    d = dict((k,0) for k in keys if k not in {'n'})
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK. I have made an edit. Try it again.

Comment: Ops! Both editing answers. It works!! Thanks:))))